# get() inside dict composition

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

New to python/programming, and working on dict composition. (python 3)

Is it possible to use the get method inside of a dict composition on the dict you're creating?

```
e.g. d = {key: d.get(key,0) + 1 for key in some_list}
```

Feel free to provide a better way of accomplishing the example, but I'm really interested in understanding if using get on the dict you're creating is possible/valid.

Comment: It's not possible because the dict gets created first, and then gets assigned to the name `d`. So, during the process of its creation (i.e. in the dict-comprehension), `d` doesn't yet exist, and you'll get a NameError (assuming you haven't made a different variable called `d` somewhere in the past)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget thanks for the additional info on whats happening behind the scenes  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, not possible. If you want a dict of counts, use the `collections.Counter` dict subclass:

```
import collections

counts = collections.Counter(some_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has dedicated class for handing this kind of problems - `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections
seq = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
d = collections.Counter(seq)  # Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 1})
```